# Plotting same elements of two row vectors of different sizes

Tags: matlab

Let us have

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5];
b=[4 2];
```

I want a plot of 'a' in which same elements(of `a` and `b`) get marked. I am trying but all in vain. My result should be plot of a with values 4 and 2 marked.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5];
x = 1:numel(a);
b = [2 4];
figure
plot(x, a);
hold on;
markIt = ismember(a, b);
plot(x(markIt), a(markIt), 's')
```

This produces a plot of `a`, with the elements that also belong to `b` (found with the `ismember` function) plotted (again) as a square (that's the `'s'` in the second plot command).

I am sure you can adapt this to your needs... Sorry I can't test while I'm at home.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear as to how you are going to plot `a`, but you can find the elemnts of `a` that are also in `b` using

```
a(any(bsxfun(@eq,a,b')))
```

Comment: True - but isn't `a(ismember(a,b))` both simpler, and easier to read?